# Is the operator continuous or not?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have the space $C[0,1]$ with sup-norm. If
$$f(x) =c_0 + \sum_k c_k \cos(2\pi k x)  $$
is then the operator
$$T(f(x)) =c_0 + \sum_k c_k 2\pi k \sin(2\pi k x)$$
continuous?

My attempt is to show whether it is bounded. It is close to a standard form fourier series, so if it would have been $\cos(\pi k x/1)$ I could have found the coefficients by the formula $c_k = \frac{2}{1} \int_0^1 g(x)\cdot \cos(\pi k x/1)\, dx$ and then used the explicit value to show $\|Tf\| \leq C \|f\|$. Maybe it is possible to rewrite $f(x)$ to a fourier series on $[0,1]$? But at the same time $Tf$ is close to be the derivative operator to $f$, and the derivative operator is not bounded.

Comment: $T$ is not defined on $\mathcal C([0,1])$ as not all continuous map can be written $f(x) =c_0 + \sum_k c_k \cos(2\pi k x)$.

Comment: So find a counterexample then? You mean "not all continuous maps can be written Tf(x) = ... " ?

Comment: If there's a representation $f(x)=c_0+\sum_k c_k\cos2\pi kx$ then $f(x)=f(1-x)$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First a comment. $T$ is not defined on $\mathcal C([0,1])$ as not all continuous maps can be written as $f(x) =c_0 + \sum_k c_k \cos(2\pi k x)$.*

However, let's study the continuity of $T$ on the subset $S$ of continuous maps that can be written as $f(x) =c_0 + \sum_k c_k \cos(2\pi k x)$. Consider $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\cos(2\pi n x)$. You have $\Vert f_n \Vert = \frac{1}{n}$. Therefore the sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges to zero.

However $T(f_n(\frac{1}{4 n})) = 2 \pi$ and therefore $\Vert T(f) \Vert \ge 2 \pi$. Proving that $T$ is not continuous on $S$.

Comment: "as not all continuous map" you mean "all continuous functions"? As you write f(x) and not T(f)

Comment: A map is a synonym of function in English.

Comment: So since this shows a counterexample ($f=0$) that $\|T(f)\| \leq C \|f\| does not hold?

Comment: $C >0$ can't exist as you would have the contradiction $2 \pi \le C/n$ for all integers.

Comment: Do you need to use the point $x=1/(4n)$ or could it be done with a general $x$ for $T(f_n(x))$?

Comment: Not a general $x$! $x=0$ won't work for example as $T(f_n)(0)=0$.

Comment: But if you write $T(f_n(x))=T( \frac{1}{n}\cos(2\pi n x)) = 2\pi \sin(2\pi n x)$ and then take the sup-norm?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112555/discussion-between-blux-and-mathcounterexamples-net).